# Reading a txt line by line in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, file-io, port

I am driving myself crasy trying to read this txt file in a batch file:

```
Binary  CapabilityDescriptions  Caption                                             Availability
TRUE                            Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)  2           
TRUE                            Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM4)  2           
TRUE                            Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM5)  2
```

I am trying to get the the COM number if the Caption contains the string "Intel".

Comment: Show us the code you've tried and tell us where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=4 delims=()" %%a in ('findstr "Intel(R)" findintel.txt') do echo %%a
```